# DAO, ORM and Queries

Tags: sql, orm, dao

There is a need to update one field to the same value in a heap of records. Using the DAO/ORM structure, I would retrieve each parent object, loop through each child object, update it's field, and then save it.

It would be faster to just write the SQL: update table set field = value where criteria = specified.

How do I fit these things together? Do I just stick with the dao structure:

```
for (Table t : getTableDao().getTables()){  
  for(Child c : t.getChildren()){  
    c.setValue(1);  
    getChildrenDao().save(c);  
  }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Which ORM are you using? Many allow you to write some sql if needed.

Comment: Hand crafted :O. The current project only has 5 main tables so I've quickly created a simple dao system with some basic ORM. I'll allow queries on the daos I think. The app will be deployed on very limited machines, so I am concerned with using Hibernate. Is there a light weight ORM that can be used with embedded derby?

Comment: Oh, and its a Java SE 5 based application, with Swing

Comment: I've decided to go with JPA (TopLink) for this simple database. Using a DAO structure we'll still be able to run those mass update queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, mass updates should not be done in what might be considered the "normal ORM" way, which is as you describe, looping through each object.

Any reasonable ORM has a mechanism for you to run a normal SQL update statement as you propose and that is generally the correct way to do it.

Just because you are using an ORM doesn't mean you can't take advantage of the relational set based system underneath.  Use objects when objects make sense and use SQL when SQL makes sense.